# Is Java VM defective or why does repeated use of CompilationTask and Reflections cause a software defect?

Tags: java, reflection, classloader, runnable

ISSUE RESOLVED: The code below remains defective in Java 1.8.232 but has correct behavior in Java 13.0.1. Perhaps someone at OpenJDK could look into this issue because Java 8 is still supported? It is unknown what version resolves this issue between Java 8 and Java 13.

Is Java VM defective? Or why does this repeated use of Java CompilationTask, ToolProvider.getSystemJavaCompiler, and Reflections cause a software defect?

The following code has been reduce from the original code baseline (https://github.com/peytonc), and makes use of run-time code generation, run-time compilation, and reflections API.

In the software below, a defect occurs with repeated calls to the Java compiler (to compile dynamic code at runtime) and reflections (to invoke the dynamic code). At first, all calls perform the correct calculation, but after an extended period of time, the calculations become incorrect. When the software is behaving as expected, the JVM only keeps 1 instance of each unique package/class (which seems correct to me). However, when the defect occurs, the JVM has two or more copies of the same package/class (which seems incorrect to me).

On my computer [Intel NUC, Fedora 31, OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_232-b09)], the code below produces the results below. Iterations 0-913 all show correct behavior, whereas iteration 914 shows the first defective behavior.

> INFO: Iteration #0: (c0)  (i0)  (c1)  (i1)  (c2)  (i2)  (c4)  (i4)  (c3)  (i3)  (c5)  (i5)  (c6)  (i6)  (c7)  (i7)  (c8)  (i8)  (c9)  (i9)
>
> INFO: Iteration #1: (c0)  (i0)  (c1)  (i1)  (c4)  (i4)  (c5)  (c6)  (i5)  (i6)  (c7)  (i7)  (c8)  (i8)  (c9)  (i9)  (c3)  (i3)  (c2)  (i2)
>
> INFO: Iteration #2: (c3)  (i3)  (c1)  (i1)  (c2)  (i2)  (c0)  (c4)  (i4)  (i0)  (c5)  (i5)  (c7)  (c8)  (i7)  (c9)  (i9)  (c6)  (i6)  (i8)
>
> ...
>
> INFO: Iteration #913: (c0)  (i0)  (c2)  (i2)  (c3)  (i3)  (c4)  (c5)  (i4)  (i5)  (c1)  (c6)  (i1)  (i6)  (c7)  (i7)  (c8)  (i8)  (c9)  (i9)
>
> INFO: Iteration #914: (c0)  (c1)  (c3)  (i3)  (i0)  (c2)  (i2)  (i1)
>
> ERROR: On iteration #914 id #4, actualResultsFromProgram != expectedResultFromProgram, 4!=5
>
> ERROR: On iteration #914 id #5, actualResultsFromProgram != expectedResultFromProgram, 5!=6
>
> ERROR: On iteration #914 id #6, actualResultsFromProgram != expectedResultFromProgram, 6!=7
>
> ERROR: On iteration #914 id #7, actualResultsFromProgram != expectedResultFromProgram, 7!=8
>
> ERROR: On iteration #914 id #8, actualResultsFromProgram != expectedResultFromProgram, 8!=9
>
> ERROR: On iteration #914 id #9, actualResultsFromProgram != expectedResultFromProgram, 9!=10

```
package minijava;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import javax.tools.DiagnosticCollector;
import javax.tools.JavaCompiler;
import javax.tools.JavaFileObject;
import javax.tools.StandardJavaFileManager;
import javax.tools.ToolProvider;
import javax.tools.JavaCompiler.CompilationTask;

public class Programs {
    public int species = 1;
    private static final JavaCompiler JAVA_COMPILER = ToolProvider.getSystemJavaCompiler();
    private static final int MAX_POPULATION = 10;
    private List<Program> listProgram = new ArrayList<Program>(MAX_POPULATION);
    private static final int AVAILABLE_PROCESSORS = Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors();
    private long iteration = 0;

    // The compute function will increment the first array value by one
    private static final String sourceCodeTemplate = 
            "package species0.id0; \n" +
            "import java.util.ArrayList; \n" +
            "public class GeneticProgram { \n" +
            "   public static void compute(ArrayList<Long> values00) { \n" +
            "       long value = values00.get(0); \n" +
            "       System.out.print(\" (c\" +  value + \") \"); \n" +
            "       values00.set(0, value + 1); \n" +
            "   } \n" +
            "} \n";

    public Programs() {
        System.out.println(sourceCodeTemplate);

        int errorCode = 0;
        while(errorCode == 0) {
            System.out.print("\nINFO: Iteration #" + iteration + ":");

            errorCode = createPrograms();
            if(errorCode == 0) {
                compilePrograms();
            }
            if(errorCode == 0) {
                executePrograms();
            }
            iteration++;
        }
    }

    public int createPrograms() {
        listProgram.clear();
        for(int index=0; index<MAX_POPULATION; index++) {
            String simulatedRandomSourceCode = replacePackage(sourceCodeTemplate, species, index);
            Program program = new Program(simulatedRandomSourceCode, species, index);
            program.vectors.add(new Long(index));   // this number will be incremented by 1 upon execution of program
            listProgram.add(program);
        }
        return 0;
    }

    public int compilePrograms() { 
        DiagnosticCollector<JavaFileObject> diagnostics = new DiagnosticCollector<JavaFileObject>();
        for(Program program : listProgram) {
            try (StandardJavaFileManager standardJavaFileManager = JAVA_COMPILER.getStandardFileManager(diagnostics, Locale.ENGLISH, null)) {
                Iterable<Program> javaFileObject = Arrays.asList(program);
                ProgramClassSimpleJavaFileObject programClassSimpleJavaFileObject = null;
                try {
                    programClassSimpleJavaFileObject = new ProgramClassSimpleJavaFileObject(Program.PACKAGE_SPECIES + species + "." + Program.PACKAGE_ID + program.ID + "." + Program.PROGRAM_CLASS);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    return -1;
                }
                ProgramForwardingJavaFileManager programForwardingJavaFileManager = new ProgramForwardingJavaFileManager(standardJavaFileManager, programClassSimpleJavaFileObject, program.programClassLoader);
                CompilationTask compilerTask = JAVA_COMPILER.getTask(null, programForwardingJavaFileManager, diagnostics, null, null, javaFileObject);
                if (!compilerTask.call()) {
                    System.out.println("\nERROR: compilePrograms compilerTask.call()");
                    return -1;
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return -1;
            }
        }
        return 0;
    }

    public int executePrograms() {
        List<CallableMiniJava> listCallable = new ArrayList<CallableMiniJava>(MAX_POPULATION);
        ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(AVAILABLE_PROCESSORS);

        try {
            for(Program program : listProgram) {
                listCallable.add(new CallableMiniJava(program));
            }
            for(CallableMiniJava callableMiniJava : listCallable) {
                executorService.execute(callableMiniJava);
            }
            executorService.shutdown();
            if(!executorService.awaitTermination(1000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)) {
                executorService.shutdownNow();
                int milliseconds = 1000;
                while(!executorService.awaitTermination(1000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)) {
                    milliseconds += 1000;
                    System.out.println("\nINFO: Runaway program for " + milliseconds + " milliseconds");
                }
            }

            for (Program program : listProgram) {
                long actualResultsFromProgram = program.vectors.get(0);
                long expectedResultFromProgram = program.ID + 1;
                if(actualResultsFromProgram != expectedResultFromProgram) {
                    System.out.println("\nERROR: On iteration #" + iteration + " id #" + program.ID + ", actualResultsFromProgram != expectedResultFromProgram, " + actualResultsFromProgram + "!=" + expectedResultFromProgram);
                }
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return -1;
        }
        return 0;
    }

    public static String replacePackage(String source, int species, int packageNumber) {
        return source.replaceFirst("package species[0-9][^;]*;", "package " + Program.PACKAGE_SPECIES + species + "." + Program.PACKAGE_ID + packageNumber + ";");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Programs programs = new Programs();
    }
}
```

```
package minijava;

import java.net.URI;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.tools.SimpleJavaFileObject;

public class Program extends SimpleJavaFileObject {
    public static final String PROGRAM_CLASS = new String("GeneticProgram");
    public static final String PACKAGE_SPECIES = new String("species");
    public static final String PACKAGE_ID = new String("id");
    public String source;
    public ArrayList<Long> vectors;
    public int species;
    public int ID;
    public ProgramClassLoader programClassLoader = null;

    Program(String source, int species, int ID) {
        super(URI.create("string:///" + PACKAGE_SPECIES + species + '/' + PACKAGE_ID + ID + '/' + PROGRAM_CLASS + Kind.SOURCE.extension), Kind.SOURCE);
        this.source = new String(source);
        this.species = species;
        this.ID = ID;
        vectors = new ArrayList<Long>(1);
        programClassLoader = new ProgramClassLoader(ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader());
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getCharContent(boolean ignoreEncodingErrors) {
        return source;
    }
}
```

```
package minijava;

import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class CallableMiniJava implements Runnable {
    private Program program = null;
    private Class<?> cls = null;
    private Method method = null;

    public CallableMiniJava(Program program) {
        if(program.vectors != null) {
            this.program = program;
            try {
                cls = program.programClassLoader.loadClass(Program.PACKAGE_SPECIES + program.species + "." + Program.PACKAGE_ID + program.ID + "." + Program.PROGRAM_CLASS);
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            try {
                method = cls.getMethod("compute", ArrayList.class);
            } catch (NoSuchMethodException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            } catch (SecurityException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            method.invoke(null, program.vectors);
            System.out.print(" (i" +  program.ID + ") ");
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

```
package minijava;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class ProgramClassLoader extends ClassLoader {

    public Map<String, ProgramClassSimpleJavaFileObject> mapProgramClass = new HashMap<>();

    public ProgramClassLoader(ClassLoader classLoader) {
        super(classLoader);
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?> findClass(String className) throws ClassNotFoundException {
        ProgramClassSimpleJavaFileObject programClassSimpleJavaFileObject = mapProgramClass.get(className);
        if(programClassSimpleJavaFileObject != null) {
            byte[] byteCode = programClassSimpleJavaFileObject.byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();
            return defineClass(className, byteCode, 0, byteCode.length);
        } else {
            return super.findClass(className);
        }
    }
}
```

```
package minijava;

import javax.tools.SimpleJavaFileObject;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.URI;

public class ProgramClassSimpleJavaFileObject extends SimpleJavaFileObject {
    public ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

    public ProgramClassSimpleJavaFileObject(String className) throws Exception {
        super(new URI(className), Kind.CLASS);
    }

    @Override
    public OutputStream openOutputStream() throws IOException {
        return byteArrayOutputStream;
    }
}
```

```
package minijava;

import javax.tools.FileObject;
import javax.tools.ForwardingJavaFileManager;
import javax.tools.JavaFileManager;
import javax.tools.JavaFileObject;
import javax.tools.JavaFileObject.Kind;

import java.io.IOException;

public class ProgramForwardingJavaFileManager extends ForwardingJavaFileManager<JavaFileManager> {
    private ProgramClassLoader programClassLoader;
    private ProgramClassSimpleJavaFileObject programClassSimpleJavaFileObject;

    protected ProgramForwardingJavaFileManager(JavaFileManager javaFileManager, ProgramClassSimpleJavaFileObject programClassSimpleJavaFileObject, ProgramClassLoader programClassLoader) {
        super(javaFileManager);
        this.programClassSimpleJavaFileObject = programClassSimpleJavaFileObject;
        this.programClassLoader = programClassLoader;
        this.programClassLoader.mapProgramClass.put(programClassSimpleJavaFileObject.getName(), programClassSimpleJavaFileObject);
    }

    @Override
    public JavaFileObject getJavaFileForOutput(JavaFileManager.Location location, String className, Kind kind, FileObject fileObject) throws IOException {
        return programClassSimpleJavaFileObject;
    }

    @Override
    public ClassLoader getClassLoader(Location location) {
        return programClassLoader;
    }
}
```